# Inserting data from Google Spreadsheets to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a JavaScript-only, direct method to read information from a Google Spreadsheet and use it to generate markers, InfoWindows, etc. in a Google Map (V3)?

I've done some searching and found the spreadsheet-to-map wizard but it is for V2:
http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/spreadsheetsmapwizard/makecustommap.htm

Also, I read about converting Spreadsheets to Fusion Tables, then plotting from the FT. However, is there a direct way? I tried Fusion Tables and it appeared to do some magic with InfoWindows that I had no control over.

After looking some more, it seems like the Spreadsheets API is the only way. Is there something simpler?

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, please point it out to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there is the Google Spreadsheet and Docs API, but it doesn't seem to be worth the trouble.

Better use Fusion Table APIs.

Comment: Why use the Fusion Table APIs over Google's? Explain so others asking the same question can understand too.